# How can I unit test when code throws an ImportError?

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose, nosetests

I have a Python module that tries to import a module, and if it fails, adds sets up a lightweight class to replicate some of the functionality as a fallback.

How can I write a unit test that covers both cases - when the module is present, and when the module is not present?

```
try:
    from foo import bar
except ImportError:
    class bar(object):
        def doAThing(self):
            return "blah"
```

For example, if bar is present, the unit tests will report that only the 2nd line is covered, and the rest of the module isn't. Python's coverage will report missing tests on the line with "except" to the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modules are loaded from the `sys.path` array. If you clear that array then any non-core import will fail. The following commands were run in ipython in a virtual env with access to django

```
import sys

sys.path = []

import django
... ImportError ...

import os
... No ImportError ...
```

Your other alternative is to use two virtual environments. One which has the module and one which does not. That would make it slightly more difficult to run the tests though.

If this doesn't work then you can add a path to the start of the `sys.path` that has a module that will produce an `ImportError` when loaded. This works because the first match found when searching the `sys.path` is loaded, so this can replace the real module. The following is sufficient:

*test.py*

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '.')

import foo
```

*foo/__init__.py*

```
raise ImportError()
```